# Too many 302 redirects but the are not visible in de developer console

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-302

I've made a website that looks to work on the frontend also in the console are none 302 redirects visible (see printscreen). But if i go to https://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php and check the url "https://www.digibitz.nl/" it says that their are 19 302 redirects so somewhere their is a loop and because of this loop i can not at the website to the google search console.

[image]

I did the following thing to check if the error is coming from one of the parts of the website:

- Removing the body content and check again for errors (the errors persist)
- Removing the body and header content with exception to the database checks (the errors persist)
- Removed everything in the .htaccess file (the errors persist)
- Removed the database checks (the error changed into a 500 error, but that is understandable because their is now no database connection)
- Added a new 301 redirect from https://www.digibitz.nl/ to https://www.digibitz.nl/index.php (still the errors persist)
  -Tried the solutions on https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/troubleshooting-too-many-redirects/
- check every other page but every page gives the same amount of redirects but from the page given.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Force WWW
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Force Https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>
```

I'm a beginner if it comes to redirects and the htaccess file and after hours of searching i still can't find a solution or see where the loop is coming from.

I don't know how i can find the loop, and fix it.

Thanks in advance,

Michael

Ps. sorry for the bad english it is not my native language.

Comment: Disable the acceptance of cookies for the site in your browser - and you will see the same redirect loop happening there. This appears to not be a problem on the webserver level, but in your script. It must be looking for a certain cookie, and if it does not find that, it tries to set that cookie, and redirects to the same URL again. Only tools such as this redirect checker don’t give a hoot about cookies to begin with, and so you get an endless redirect in there. Same as you would in the browser of any site visitor, if they did not accept cookies either.

Comment: Thank you so much! The language cookie was the problem. You helpt me out big time.